# Node Reply in Drupal 7

Tags: forms, drupal, drupal-7, reply

Can I do something like this.

1. On specific ***node type*** there should be a form attached with few fields.
2. Once someone sends *reply* through that form. It first goes into "*Moderation area*" to a specific role ( i.e, *Reply Administrator*)
3. Once *Reply Administrator* approves that reply the same information goes to the **Author** of the node. Otherwise it just stays there.

I was wondering if I can do whole something like this through NODE so I can import my wordpress replies easily.

You can check website and register yourself on [www.emergingstars.com](http://www.emergingstars.com) for more clear example.

I am using Drupal 7 with web forms in it any help would be appreciated.

Regards,
Amjad

Answer (score 0):

With comments module (core) options you can do this. With rules you can notify to the author.